# Locating and removing a delayed resque job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I have a resque job that got caught up in some bad code and is infinitely getting reque'd after failing over repeatedly. I'd like to remove the job manually, somehow, but I'm not sure what the name of the job is in the redis namespace. It isn't in 'failed' because I'm catching the actual exception. In the exception, I add the job back to the resque queue using Resque.enqueue_in(). How do I figure out what the name of the job is in redis so I can delete the key/job from ever happening?

Answer (score 3):

Resque poll a redis `list` that  essentially a queue if you want to remove a message from the redis then you can try this

```
require "rubygems"
require "redis"
require 'redis/namespace'
redis = Redis.new
namespace ||= :resque

@redis = Redis::Namespace.new(namespace, :redis => redis)
## If you dont know how does the job payload look like then find inside the list
## normally the payload look like this 
## {'class' => 'ProcessCSV' , args => ['1'] }.to_json.inpsect 
list_job_payloads = @redis.lrange "queue:[my queue name]",0,-1

## then finally remove from the list
@redis.lrem "queue:[my_queue_name]",0,value
```

But I guess more better approach would be to delete the job via resque like this

Considering that the below is the job payload push to your redis list by resque

```
 { 'class' => 'ProcessCSV', 'args' => ['1'] }
```

Then you can delete the payload using

```
 Resque::Job.destroy(queue, 'ProcessCSV', '1')
```

It also describe in more detail over [here](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/job.rb#L71-L94)