# Remove resque jobs permanently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

Is there a way to permanently remove jobs from a resque queue? The following commands remove the jobs, but when I restart the workers and the resque server, the jobs load back up.

```
Resque::Job.destroy("name_queue", Class)
```

OR

```
Resque.remove_queue("name_queue")
```

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805796/locating-and-removing-a-delayed-resque-job/13855503#13855503

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're not removing the specific instance of the job that you added to your Redis server through resque. So when you remove the queue then add it back when you restart the server, all the data from that queue could still be in your Redis server. You can work around this in your job.perform depending on your implementation. For instance, if you want to manipulate a model through resque you could check to see if that model has been destroyed before manipulating it.